# Новые файлы в git

Tags: git, git-rm

Почему все новые файлы становятся untracked?

Команда `git add` автоматически добавляет файл в коммит, а `git rm --cached` снова делает его untracked.

Я хочу добавить файл в коммит и если добавил неправильный файл удалить его из коммита.
Проблем у добавлением нету, а вот с удалением через `git rm --cached` файл опять же становится untracked.

И можно ли посмотреть список файлов добавленных в коммит?

Comment: Если не было фиксации, то чтобы удалить файл и из репозитория и с диска не пользуйтесь `--cached`, просто `git rm <файл>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл никогда не был закоммичен, он по определению еще не отслеживается, `untracked`.  В этом случае нет никаких предыдущих версий файла, с которыми мы можем сравнить текущий файл и отобразить изменения, доступные для коммита и других действий.
Отобразить  файлы заккомиченные ранее можно посмотрев историю коммитов

```
git log -p -2
```

Добавленные но не закоммиченные файлы отображаются командой

```
git status
```

Comment: `git status --ignored`.

Answer (score -3):

> Почему все новые файлы становятся untracked?

А почему должно быть наоборот?

> можно ли посмотреть список файлов добавленных в коммит?

```
git status # покажет файлы, которые добавлены в следующий коммит
```

или

```
git show <commit-hash>
```

или

```
git show --stat <commit-hash>
```